# Issue in CSS nth child and nth type of for class

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

My limitation is that I cannot update the HTML structure as we are using a cloud based platform for this. My code is here at fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2RqmU/733/

```
.BreadCrumb.crumb-line.lia-breadcrumb.lia-component-common-widget-breadcrumb .lia-list-standard-inline .lia-link-navigation.crumb-category.lia-breadcrumb-category.lia-breadcrumb-forum:nth-of-type(2){
    display:none;
}
```

I need to hide the second link, i.e. About the Community in the breadcrumb. Classes are same, so I was using nth-child,but its not working.

Comment: I already checked that answer, but it still didn't work.

Comment: try this `.BreadCrumb.crumb-line.lia-breadcrumb.lia-component-common-widget-breadcrumb .lia-list-standard-inline li:nth-child(3) { display:none}`